# How to list updated projects on multi module configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot

I need your help because in my module I have several projects, see:

[image]

I'm looking for a way to have a document that list the projects updated during the sprint (the last 2 weeks) in order to know which project I need to redeploy.

Do you have an idea about how I can do this?

We have to check the history of each subproject manually.

We are on Spring Boot, Java 20, Maven we use GitHub Actions and Kubernetes.

This is one of the pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.bootcamp.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>BootCampProject</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.bootcam</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootCampApi</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>bootCampApi</name>
    <description>bootCampApi</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Parent pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.bootcamp.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>BootCampProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
        <relativePath></relativePath>
    </parent>

</project>
```

Comment: Does it write some message on mouseover? Can you share the POM files ? it might be helpful. What is it your maven version?

Comment: the post is updated with the pom.xml

Comment: Can you add the parent as well ?

Comment: the post is updated with the parent pom.xml

Comment: no ideas? i haven't fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit late, but what you can do is this:

1. Create a new git tag at the end of each sprint, let's say you have now tag `v1` in production
2. Once you have finished the sprint, you can assign new git tag - `v2` to your repository. Then just compare these 2 tags to see what files have been touched:

```
git --no-pager diff --name-status v1 v2
```

You can then add some bahs scripting here to check that files in `src` were modified or some other files like pom.xml etc that you care about. This is already a customization. But with this I think you should be goot to go.